# I may no longer symbolicate crashlog with atos

Tags: ios, xcode, symbolicatecrash, quincykit

Since the latest few Xcode version I am not able to symbolicate the crash-logs I receive through Quncykit. When I execute the usual:

> xcrun atos -arch armv7s -o * -l 2480260 0x0000000100271884

I get error:

> atos cannot load symbols for the file In ArrivoHD for architecture
>   armv7s.

Same with:

> atos -arch armv7 -o inArrivoHD 0x100084000 0x000000010012bda4

While if I execute:

> xcrun atos -arch arm64 -o * -l 0x100014000 0x00000001000bbda4

I am retuned the latter code along with the name of the app.

What is wrong with atos and the most recent Xcode versions and how to symbolicate the crash logs again? Of course waiting for Apple to provide them herself on the portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple answered me, apparently the old command those not work any longer; the right command is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/atos -arch arm64 -o * -l
```